# How to save java optimization flags?

Tags: java, optimization, jruby, flags

I want to configure a standard Java environment - for example --server and --fast should always be passed to Java and JRuby. Is there a config file for that?

Since I did not find any place to configure, I wrote a wrapper for JRuby(installed via RVM) like that:

```
[path]/jruby --server --fast "$@"
```

Unfortunately all kinds of stuff will start failing like that. If started with the same flags without the wrapper, things work out fine.

Answer (score 1):

I've not heard of one.  And maybe that's because the idea of a "one size fits all" configuration for Java application doesn't really work.

But if you want to do this, it should be trivial to implement a wrapper script that calls the relevant `java` executable with a fixed set of JVM options.  For example, here's a really dumb version:

```
#!/bin/sh
java -server -fast "$@"
```

Throwing away all JVM options in the input arguments is simple too, though I'm not going to try it here ...

---

The difficult part is trying to get some application to use the wrapper script *without changing the application* to change the path it uses for the `java` command.  There isn't a good answer for that, IMO.

The root problem is that the standard `java` command does not support reading JVM options from a configuration file.

Comment: That's what I did an hour ago. I have a jruby setup via rvm. When I wrap the jruby binary with a bash script (just like yours), lots of ruby on rails will fail(for example: "rake: line 9: require: command not found"). That's why I was searching for the standard way. But as you said, there probably is none. At least google doesn't reveal any.

Answer (score 0):

Why not edit ~/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.5.6/bin/jruby? Easy enough to change `-client` to `-server -fast`.

I believe that this will be fixed in 1.6, which is about to be released.

Comment: Well, the mentioned file is a binary. What I already did is write a wrapper around it. This led to the aforementioned problems.